How to change the gain for this amplifier?
I'm modifying a hot-chassis TV to add a Y/C input. To isolate the inputs, I'm using an optocoupler with the following circuit:

The jungle IC, however, requires a 4.5Vpp signal on the chroma line:

Is it possible to alter this circuit to increase the incoming video-level Chroma input to the required 4.5Vpp, or do I need a separate gain stage?

What's VCC2? That's the upper limit of how far you can pull Vout using Q4.

Also note that, as the schematic says, the load you're attaching needs to be high-impedance; is that the case for your IC? If not, you need a buffer stage, anyways.

generally, that "Recommended isolated Video interface circuit" looks like something you build when opamps are expensive, hard to get, and you want to save a few cents per device, as you're producing many thousand; none of that applies to you.. It feels to me as if this whole circuit you're using is probably a bad idea and you'd be better off with something else.

@MarcusMüller VCC2 is 12V. The input is a video processor IC, so it should be high impedance (no 75 ohm terminations around here). This is the only isolated video I could find, and looking at the original board for this TV, it uses a TLP651, which is pin-compatible with the one I'm using (HCPL-4562. I got this circuit from the datasheet). I've modified a similar TV (also hot chassis but slightly newer) and the results were great.

That circuit has inadequate bandwidth for your application. It won't work.

@KevinWhite I've replaced R10 for a 50 ohm resistor and it worked perfectly.

@hjf - surprising - the bandwidth of the majority of transistor output opto-couplers are too low for video applications. Also even the value of R6 (9.1k) would create a significant roll-off above ~1MHz in conjunction with the capacitance at that node.

@KevinWhite that's a ~ 12 MHz wideband isolator

@hjf If you hadn't already have a proven design, I'd remove all the output transistors, and on the output side only keep R7 and R9, and then do the adjustable gain when amplifying the voltage at pin6 with a video-bandwidth opamp with a potentiometer :)

@MarcusMüller - ok, I stand corrected. What's the part number?

HCPL-4562, @KevinWhite, see hjf's comment above

@MarcusMüller - thanks.
